# How to define multivalue for an array of fields in solr

Tags: solr, nested-attributes

I have xml documents with a set of tags occuring multiple times. For e.g. `<Address>` tag in the below document. In other words the parent tag Address occurs 2 times.

I want to search for `Name=ABCD` and `ZipCode=33333` and would like solr to return response similar to the "Response Doc" given below. Is it possible to do this in solr4.0 without defining Address to be a Multivalued single field with all the subfields separated by a separator?

**DOC**

```
<doc>
      <Name>ABCD</Name>
      <CompanyName>1234</CompanyName>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1> 1725 ABCD Drive </AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
          <City>Miami</City>
          <State>FL</State>
          <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
          <AddressType>Home</AddressType>
      </Address>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1> 16551 business blvd </AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
          <City>Miami</City>
          <State>FL</State>
          <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
          <AddressType>Business</AddressType>
      </Address>
</doc>
<doc>
      <Name>XYZWR</Name>
      <CompanyName>1234</CompanyName>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1> 1725 ABCD Drive </AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
          <City>Miami</City>
          <State>FL</State>
          <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
          <AddressType>Home</AddressType>
      </Address>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1> 16551 business blvd </AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
          <City>Phoenix</City>
          <State>AZ</State>
          <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
          <AddressType>Business</AddressType>
      </Address>
</doc>
```

**Response DOC**

```
   <doc>
          <Name>ABCD</Name>
          <CompanyName>1234</CompanyName>
          <Address>
              <AddressLine1> 1725 ABCD Drive </AddressLine1>
              <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
              <City>Miami</City>
              <State>FL</State>
              <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
              <AddressType>Home</AddressType>
          </Address>
          <Address>
              <AddressLine1> 16551 business blvd </AddressLine1>
              <AddressLine2> </Address Line2>
              <City>Miami</City>
              <State>FL</State>
              <Zipcode>33333</Zipcode>
              <AddressType>Business</AddressType>
          </Address>
    </doc>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to store de-normalized. There is no way around it. So, we store fields like

```
home_addressline1
home_zipcode
etc.,
```

Coming to searches, you can have dynamic fields - 2 kinds of dynamic fields, and then have a copy field that copies appropriately into these dynamic fields

```
address_*
*_home (and/or) *_business etc.,
```

when user wants to search zipcode and doesnt care about which "type" of address has it, you use address_* , whereas when user wants to search for "Home type" only, then you use *_home and requests start pouring in for searching only a certain address type pretty soon :)